# Swift POST Request not working

Tags: node.js, swift, http, post

I have this server set up with NodeJS that can receive a name and an email and let me know if they match.It can also let me know if the received data is not valid.

This is my code in swift:

```
func post() {
    let parameters = [
        "email": "windvaan@live.nl",
        "password": "Dittoenbram1234!"
    ]

    let url = NSURL(string: "http://localhost:3000/login")
    var request = URLRequest(url: url! as URL)

    request.httpMethod = "POST"

    guard let httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions.prettyPrinted) else {
        return
    }

    request.httpBody = httpBody

    let session = URLSession.shared
    session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
        if let data = data {
            do {
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
                print(json)
            } catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }.resume()

}
```

When I call this function my server says that the data is not valid, but the data I put as the parameters is. I believe it has something to do with this function and the parameters because my server is working fine. Thx in advance!

Comment: Unrelated, but the server doesn't care at all about pretty printed text. The option is meaningless in this case. Omit the `options` parameter (also when receiving the response).

Comment: I'm glad you found your solution (in your answer, below). In the future, if (a) you have `data`, but (b) `jsonObject(with:)` fails, you can often print `String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)` and you'll see the body of the response from the server which can sometimes give you clues as to what went wrong. Unrelated, but if you instantiated `url` as a `URL(string: "...")` instead of `NSURL`, you wouldn't have to cast it later. Don't use `NS` classes when there is an equivalent Swift type.

Comment: Thank you very much, that was useful!

Comment: Like, EXTREMELY useful for trying to figure out what errors my server is giving me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out, I had to add in this in my swift file:

```
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
```

Answer (score 0):

As per as your parameters value, it's not in valid JSON format. 
When you print your parameters value it will print - ["password": "Dittoenbram1234!", "email": "windvaan@live.nl"] , which is invalid.

You need to have this format - { email = "windvaan@live.nl"; password = "Dittoenbram1234!";}

**For this**

Replace this -

```
let parameters = [
       "email": "windvaan@live.nl",
       "password": "Dittoenbram1234!"
   ]
```

With this -

```
let parameters: NSDictionary = [
        "email": "windvaan@live.nl",
        "password": "Dittoenbram1234!"
    ]
```

Hope this will help you. :)

Comment: Thx for the reply but I already figured it out just a second ago: i had to add in this: request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

Comment: Great ;)
Yeah you have to add these two as request header type too.